# CPU High consumption when exiting/restarting from sleep mode (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, cpu, cpu-usage

I just noticed that when I restart my computer from sleeping mode the CPU consumption goes very high for a couple of second, did you know why ?

[image: CPU high consumption]

It goes to 126.5 watt while in never goes above 40-50 watt.

Answer (score 0):

It's becasue your computer suddenly has to read and process a lot of data, so it automatically throttels up to make sure that those demands can certainly be meet. It's nothing to worry about and completelly normal.